# Why is my SSIS build failing from TFS 2015?

Tags: tfs, ssis

I have a SSIS package and I can successfully build it on the build server at the command line interactively with:

`C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" SSIS_Sync\SSIS_Sync.dtproj /Build Development"`

but it only works when run from an `Administrator: Command Prompt` and not from a command prompt as the build username.

Any ideas on how to run the command prompt build step as administrator in TFS? The service account for the build agent is in the local Administrators group on the server.

The error I see in the logs is:

```
2016-10-09T17:55:12.2253192Z Starting task: Compile SSIS Packages
2016-10-09T17:55:12.2253192Z Executing the following command-line. (workingFolder = C:\Agents\TFSBuild\_work\1\s\DataResync)
2016-10-09T17:55:12.2253192Z "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" SSIS_Sync\SSIS_Sync.dtproj /Build Development
2016-10-09T17:55:12.2253192Z Error message highlight pattern: 
2016-10-09T17:55:12.2253192Z Warning message highlight pattern: 
2016-10-09T17:55:12.2253192Z C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" SSIS_Sync\SSIS_Sync.dtproj /Build Development"
2016-10-09T17:55:12.6315610Z Finishing task: CmdLine
```

The second to last line in that log has been run on the build server successfully in an admin command prompt window!

Comment: That error message is not very useful... I don't actually see an error. Is this the only package that fails? What is the Protection Level of the package? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141747.aspx If it's any of the "encrypt with user key" ones, that could be the issue. Which version of SSIS exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some test, you just need to add your build service account in local Administrator ,then the command should run as Administrator mode.

Moreover, You could either call ["runas" in a normal commandline call](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx), or reconfigure the build agent to run under the specific user you desire.(Such as local Administrator on the build agent)

**Update**

According to the release note. TFS2015 is not  compatibly with windows server2016. The support version should be TFS15 and above.

[image]

Source Link: **[Requirements and compatibility](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/requirements)**

Comment: And, the machine had to be restartet after the permission changed.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I think the issue is because I'm running on Windows 2016 Eval. I built a new server on Windows 2012 R2 and it builds OK. I had already put the TFS service account into the local Administrators group on both boxes.

Comment: Seems your issue has figured out, according to the release note. TFS2015 is not fully compatibly with windows server2016. The support version should be TFS15 and above, more details please see my update answer.

Comment: Thanks, I was getting ahead of myself with the shiny new toys.. :)